# How to control spacing between words using CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm formatting a webpage that contains a bio.  The word spacing is off as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Please advise on how I can alter my CSS to get proper word spacing:

```css
.column1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.column2 {
            
}
     
p { 
  color: #000000; 
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  line-height: 24px; 
  margin: 0 0 24px; 
  text-align: justify; 
  text-justify: inter-word; 
}
```

```html
<div class="column1"> 
<img alt="" src="/portals/2/Martin%20Profile.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" title="" />
<br> Apptiv Solutions
<br> Founded 2015 
<br> Martin Muldoon
<br> Founder 
</div> 

<div class="column2">
<p>Martins introduction to the Brewing Industry first took place in 1995. While working as a Development Engineer at Trigen Energy Corporation, he was called upon to assist in the acquisition of the power plant assets of the Coors Brewery in Golden Colorado. To this day, the Coors plant is the largest single site brewery on earth providing 30% of all beer in the U.S.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing `text-align: justify` declared on the nested `p` tag will resolve this issue.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's caused by the justification. You a have few typos as well, an extra `"`, `normal-family` would be `font-family` & `letter-spacing` should have either `px`, `em`, `rem`, etc unit values.

You can set `text-align` to left on mobile view with a media query if you wish to keep justification on desktop. Otherwise just remove justification for all views to avoid that spacing (tweak values to your benefit):

```
@media (max-width: 414px) {
  p {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

[**Working Resizable Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/vqgj2h7h/6/)

Comment: I appreciate your response. The solution offered by UncaughtTypeError worked and he was just a tad bit sooner to answer.  Thank you!